# CakePhp 2.6.3 Not Working on PHP 7

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, php-7, apache2.4

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Class 'String' not found in /var/www/html/hrportal/lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php:340
Stack trace: 0 /var/www/html/hrportal/lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php(742): Debugger::trace(Array)1 /var/www/html/hrportal/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(229): Debugger->outputError(Array) /var/www/html/hrportal/app/Controller/AppController.php(72): ErrorHandler::handleError(8, 'Undefined index...', '/var/www/html/h...', 72, Array) 3 /var/www/html/hrportal/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php(243): AppController->beforeFilter(Object(CakeEvent)) 4 /var/www/html/hrportal/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(676): CakeEventManager->dispatch(Object(CakeEvent)) 5 /var/www/html/hrportal/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php(154): Controller->startupProcess() 6 /var/www/html/hrportal/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php(92): ExceptionRenderer->_getController(Object(FatalErrorException)) 7 /var/www/html/hrportal/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(126): ExceptionRenderer->__construct(Object(FatalErrorException)) 8 in /var/www/html/hrportal/lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php on line**340**

This error is coming as i have upgraded my system to PHP 7.0.

I have CakePHP application , that was working on 5.5.9 Perfectly , 
Now this error is coming please help .

Comment: I have same issue

Comment: @SandipGhadge do install 5.6 it will get you working .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP 2.6 is not compatible with PHP 7
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html

Comment: I Have changed back to PHP 5.6 then also error is not going .

Comment: Got it working , now i have installed both PHP 5.6 and PHP 7 ,when i Switch to PHP 5.6 it is working fine now , Thanks

Comment: @AyushPant than please accept the answer to help others to understand it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> try cakephp 2.9 release if you don't want to use 3.x

Answer (score 0):

According to Cakephp 2.x documentation. Below are the PHP
[Requirements](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#requirements) for Cakephp 2.x

> PHP 5.3.0 or greater (CakePHP version 2.6 and below support PHP 5.2.8
>   and above). CakePHP version 2.8.0 and above support PHP 7. To use PHP
>   above 7.1 you may need to install mcrypt via PECL. See Security for
>   more information.

Answer (score -2):

For PHP 7 you have to use 2.9.x

Comment: there was already an answer that was exactly this content. Why adding a duplicate?